# Spark cluster fails after running and no exception thrown

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr

I'm trying to run a stand-alone Spark application on EC2 Yarn command line. I'm submitting the following spark-submit script:

```
./bin/spark-submit   --class PageRankGraphX   --master yarn-cluster  --properties-file spark-defaults.conf.2   --executor-memory 2G   --total-executor-cores 5   ./SparkPageRank-assembly-1.0.jar s3://linkfilefull/full/links_small.txt s3://conansoutputbucket/smalloutput.txt 10 0.15 2
```

This is the output - there is no exception or error thrown, the job simply fails after running:

```
15/04/15 21:27:03 INFO yarn.Client: Application report from ASM:
         application identifier: application_1429126831428_0027
         appId: 27
         clientToAMToken: null
         appDiagnostics:
         appMasterHost: ip-172-31-1-67.eu-west-1.compute.internal
         appQueue: default
         appMasterRpcPort: 0
         appStartTime: 1429133214320
         yarnAppState: RUNNING
         distributedFinalState: UNDEFINED
         appTrackingUrl: http://172.31.10.227:9046/proxy/application_1429126831428_0027/
         appUser: hadoop
15/04/15 21:27:04 INFO yarn.Client: Application report from ASM:
         application identifier: application_1429126831428_0027
         appId: 27
         clientToAMToken: null
         appDiagnostics:
         appMasterHost: ip-172-31-1-67.eu-west-1.compute.internal
         appQueue: default
         appMasterRpcPort: 0
         appStartTime: 1429133214320
         yarnAppState: FINISHED
         distributedFinalState: FAILED
         appTrackingUrl: http://172.31.10.227:9046/proxy/application_1429126831428_0027/A
         appUser: hadoop
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this or how I could investigate? When I try to access the yarn logs, it says logs are disabled or not ready.

Comment: If S3 logging is enabled (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-manage-view-web-log-files.html) the yarn logs will be in S3. See what error the application master is emitting.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score -2):

Check out [Amazon's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-connect-ui-console.html) on enabling access to the web UI of Hadoop.  Once in the UI, you can check the stderr output for the application, where the exception will most likely be.  As others mentioned, this log will also be available on S3.